# Converting a DateTime String to a Specific Pattern in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I just wanted to now if there is a efficient way to convert DateTime String to a Specific Pattern in Nodejs.

Example:

I will receive a string `StartDateTime = "2019-10-17 09:00:00"`
and i wanted to converto to two variables.
The output spected will be like:

```
StartDate = "2019-10-17"
StartTime = "09%3A00%3A00"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `const [StartDate, StartTime] = StartDateTime.split(' ');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `split` at the space and use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) on the resulting array:

```js
const startDateTime = "2019-10-17 09:00:00"
const [StartDate, StartTime] = startDateTime.split(' ').map(encodeURIComponent);

console.log(StartDate)
console.log(StartTime)
```